# mysql_query doesn´t work in custom php functions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting a mysql query to work within a function. I don't understand why this works:

```
    $datetime = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

    $query = "INSERT INTO 1_posts (title_post, time_post, key_words_post, content_post) VALUES ('$title2', '$datetime', '$keywords2', '$text2')";

    mysql_query($query, $con);
```

but this does not:

```
function insert_post($title2, $keywords2, $text2)
{

    $datetime = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

    $query = "INSERT INTO 1_posts (title_post, time_post, key_words_post, content_post) VALUES ('$title2', '$datetime', '$keywords2', '$text2')";

    mysql_query($query, $con);

}
```

Of course, I have a connection to the db, and I am calling the function. I tried to debug with some echos and I found out that the function stops ant mysql_query, but I have no idea why.

Comment: date('m/d/Y h:i:s a'); is short for date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

Comment: The mysql* functions are deprecated in php. You you should be using mysqli* functions or PDO. Additionally, you may want to implement some sort of error handling.

Answer (score 8):

```
function insert_post($title2, $keywords2, $text2)
{
 global $con;
    $datetime = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

    $query = "INSERT INTO 1_posts (title_post, time_post, key_words_post, content_post) VALUES ('$title2', '$datetime', '$keywords2', '$text2')";

    mysql_query($query, $con);

}
```

is a dirty way to get it working ($con is not set in your function). But please please take a look at PDO!

Comment: Please point out how this is different from and/or fixes the issues.

Comment: How about: Declaring `$con` as a global var enables access to it within the function. I'm more inclined to go with PDO though too.

Comment: $con is not necessary in mysql calls. it'll default to using the last opened connection if one isn't explicitly specified. you only need the $con parameter if you've got multiple connections open and have to choose between them.

Comment: In the code given in the question, `$con` is being passed to `mysql_query`, but is not declared as a global.